# Trying to get Tomcat to use Windows-ROOT certificate store

Tags: windows, ssl, tomcat9

I've been trying to modify a Tomcat 9 install to use the Windows Certificate Store (certificate is installed under Trusted Root Certification Authorities from a PFX file I generated from the Entrust certificates, and has the alias "tomcat" assigned to it. This is on Server 2019, with Oracle Java installed. Java -version reports 18.0.1.1 and so does javac -version.

When I start Tomcat, I get this exception

```
15-Jul-2022 08:28:50.561 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-2443]]
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1051)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:556)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:746)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Alias name [tomcat] does not identify a key entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:107)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:234)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1240)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1048)
        ... 13 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Alias name [tomcat] does not identify a key entry
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:337)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:105)
        ... 20 more
```

Here's the relevant connector section for the SSL connection

```
    <Connector port="2443" scheme="https" secure="true"
                sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation"
                SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig hostName="localhost"
                    sslProtocol="TLS"
                    protocols="TLSv1.3,+TLSv1.2">
            <Certificate 
                certificateKeystoreFile=""
                certificateKeystoreProvider="SunMSCAPI"
                certificateKeyAlias="tomcat"
                certificateKeystoreType ="Windows-ROOT" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

I found a question on here where someone had provided some Java code to verify the certificate installed and available, I made a couple of minor modifications (not changing the functionality, just not listing all certificates)

```
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import java.security.KeyStore;
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT");
ks.load(null, null);

Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();

System.out.println("Examining " + ks.size() + " aliases ");
while (aliases.hasMoreElements())
{
    String ka = aliases.nextElement();
    if (ks.isKeyEntry(ka))
    {
        System.out.println(ka + " is a key entry.");
    }
}
```

When I run this using JShell, the output is this...

```
Examining 35 aliases
tomcat is a key entry.
```

I'm far from a Tomcat expert, but I've been going through documentation on this, and pulling bits and pieces from all over the place, trying to save my sanity and my hair.

I'm sure it's something simple I'm doing wrong and not understanding, so I am willing to accept my lumps if I've done something stupid.

Comment: "PFX file I generated from the Entrust certificates" For your own certificate chain, i.e. the one you use to identify your server, you should have a PFX file with the key, your certificates and the certificates above it up to (but preferably excluding) the root.

Comment: Yes, the PFX file has the key, the cert to be used for the website, and the chain of certificates.

Comment: Right, OK. Now the next step: the trusted root store is not meant for your own certs, instead you should assign the certificates to the machine itself, or the user under which the server operates. Have you tried different stores? As a "trust store" is for trusted certs - those that help verify the other entities, and therefore doesn't make sense.

Comment: Okay, I removed the certificate from Trusted root, and reinstalled it into the Personal store for the computer. (Opened MMC, added the Certificates plugin, and specified to work on the local computer, rather than a user). I updated server.xml to use Windows-MY rather than -ROOT, restarted Tomcat and still get the same error.

Comment: By the way, thanks very much for helping with this.

Comment: I just tried using the Certificates manager pointed to the certificates store as seen by the service account for Tomcat, added the certificate to the Tomcat9\Personal store, and restarting Tomcat, and still at the same point. So I currently have the tomcat certificate in the Computer Personal, and the Tomcat9\Personal stores

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve it. If I'm violating policy by answering my own question, let me know.

The issue ended up being that Tomcat was running as a service using on of the built-in Service types. I changed it to use a normal account, and ensured that the new account was able to run as a service. I added the certificate to that user's certificate store, and it was able to run with no errors (I was starting to wonder if I'd recognize an error free startup).

Still some more verifications to do, but that looks like it solves this (and I don't think I saw that mentioned anywhere).

I saw someone on the Tomcat-User mailing list suggest trying to run Tomcat as the OPs normal account and see if that helped, and that gave my head a kick in the right direction.